# FileUpload ERROR

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have the following code to upload files:

```
package upload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@WebServlet("/uploadServer")
public class uploadServer extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "uploads";
private static final int THRESHOLD_SIZE     = 1024 * 1024 * 3;  // 3MB
private static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE      = 1024 * 1024 * 40; // 40MB
private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE   = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB

public uploadServer() {
    super();

}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      // checks if the request actually contains upload file
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("Request does not contain upload data");
        writer.flush();
        return;
    }

    // configures upload settings
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
    factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

    // constructs the directory path to store upload file
    String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
        + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
    // creates the directory if it does not exist
    File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
    if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
        uploadDir.mkdir();
    }

    try {
        // parses the request's content to extract file data
        List formItems = upload.parseRequest((RequestContext) request);
        Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

        // iterates over form's fields
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
            // processes only fields that are not form fields
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                File storeFile = new File(filePath);

                // saves the file on disk
                item.write(storeFile);
            }
        }
        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        request.setAttribute("message", "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
}
```

And the HTML file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Files using XMLHttpRequest - Minimal</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function fileSelected() {
    var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    if (file) {
      var fileSize = 0;
      if (file.size > 1024 * 1024)
        fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / (1024 * 1024)) / 100).toString() + 'MB';
      else
        fileSize = (Math.round(file.size * 100 / 1024) / 100).toString() + 'KB';

      document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + file.name;
      document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: ' + fileSize;
      document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + file.type;
    }
  }

  function uploadFile() {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "uploadServer", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
  }

  function uploadProgress(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = percentComplete.toString() + '%';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('progressNumber').innerHTML = 'unable to compute';
    }
  }

  function uploadComplete(evt) {
    /* This event is raised when the server send back a response */
    alert(evt.target.responseText);
  }

  function uploadFailed(evt) {
    alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
  }

  function uploadCanceled(evt) {
    alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the connection.");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Upload.aspx">
<div class="row">
  <label for="fileToUpload">Select a File to Upload</label><br />
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelected();"/>
</div>
<div id="fileName"></div>
<div id="fileSize"></div>
<div id="fileType"></div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />
</div>
<div id="progressNumber"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i run the programm and try to upload some file i get the following error message:

**There was an error: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext**

Can you help me, why i get this message and what i should change to run the programm

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were errors in the following statements:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
```

I didn't find any jar file in internet to import these above classes. Try this solution: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api